# ColorTranslator gives incorrect result for SystemColors.HotTrack and Color.Transparent

Tags: c#, colors, devexpress, converters

### Environment

C#, .NET 4.5, DevExpress 13.2.7, Visual Studio 2013

### Goal

A colour should be selected, then stored and finally retrieved for use.

### Description

The users of my application are to select a `System.Drawing.Color` (preferably using a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.ColorEdit`) which the application will store until the colour is needed. This is currently done by converting the colour into a HTML string which is stored. When needed, the `string` is converted back to a `System.Drawing.Color`.

This works for most colours but not when it comes to `SystemColors.HotTrack`. When this colour is converted into a HTML string and then back to a colour it becomes `SystemColors.Highlight` instead. See code below.

```
var hotTrackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
//hotTrackColor   "{Name=HotTrack, ARGB=(255, 0, 102, 204)}"   System.Drawing.Color

var htmlColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(hotTrackColor);
//htmlColor   "highlight"   string

var shouldBeHotTrackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(htmlColor);
//shouldBeHotTrackColor   "{Name=Highlight, ARGB=(255, 51, 153, 255)}"   System.Drawing.Color
```

Using the methods `ColorTranslator.ToWin32` and `ColorTranslator.FromWin32` gives a colour not recognized as `SystemColors.HotTrack` even though the colour itself is the same. This render the `DevExpress.XtraEditors.ColorEdit` component unable to show which colour is selected and therefore this does not seem like a suitable solution.

Using the methods `ColorTranslator.ToOle` and `ColorTranslator.FromOle` gives a correct result for `SystemColors.HotTrack` but does not convert `Color.Transparent` correct. See code below

```
var transparentColor = Color.Transparent;
//transparentColor   "{Name=Transparent, ARGB=(0, 255, 255, 255)}"   System.Drawing.Color

var oleColor = ColorTranslator.ToOle(transparentColor);
//oleColor   16777215   int

var shouldBeTransparentColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(oleColor);
//shouldBeTransparentColor   "{Name=White, ARGB=(255, 255, 255, 255)}"   System.Drawing.Color
```

### Questions

1. Why do not the methods in `ColorTranslator` translate all colours correct?
2. Where can I read more about this problem?
3. What should I do to, in a simple way, reach my goal?

### Update 2014-03-07

OK, it seems like there are no single method that would solve the problem for me.
Therefore, I have used swandog's solution with a twist. I use the colour name when storing the colour, and when translating the name back to a colour I do this:

```
//Translate from name, as suggested by swandog.
var translatedColor = Color.FromName(storedColor);

if (!translatedColor.IsKnownColor)
{
    //If the original colour was a custom colour (not a known colour) then
    //the stored colour will contain a HTML-string, like "ff12aadd".

    //Ignore the first two characters (the alpha) and hope
    //that all custom colours uses "ff" as alpha.
    var htmlString = "#" + storedColor.Substring(2);

    translatedColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(htmlString);
}
```

This way, I get the correct colours and can still use custom colours.
So far, it has worked out nicely for me.

Comment: This is quite inevitable, these conversions throw information away.  ToHtml() makes you lose *Name*, ToOle() makes you lose *alpha*, ToWin32() makes you lose RGB order.  If you don't want that to happen then don't convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the source for the `ToHTML` method at http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator.cs, you can see that both `HotTrack` and `Highlight` are going to result in the same string.

```
switch (c.ToKnownColor()) {
    case KnownColor.ActiveBorder: colorString = "activeborder"; break;
    case KnownColor.GradientActiveCaption:
    case KnownColor.ActiveCaption: colorString = "activecaption"; break;
    ...
    case KnownColor.HotTrack:
    case KnownColor.Highlight: colorString = "highlight"; break;
    ...
}
```

The Custom colors tab in the `DevExpress.XtraEditors.ColorEdit` control is what will cause you problems as they won't translate back into the named colors that are in the Web and System tabs.  What I would do is hide the Custom tab

```
colorEdit1.Properties.ShowCustomColors = false;
```

and then use `Color.Name` and `Color.FromName` to save and restore your colors:

```
Color c = colorEdit1.Color;
var colorName = c.Name;
Color restoredColor = Color.FromName(colorName);
```